# How to lock cookie to machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, session-cookies

As a result of a penetration testing process, I've been advised to lock cookies to the machine it was set on to stop it from being transferred and used to login elsewhere.

The app is Rails based.

Does anyone know how I would go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can't really lock a cookie to a single machine, you CAN ensure that a particular cookie is only used by a particular IP address, which is usually what people mean with this security tip.  It's best to maintain that mapping in the server-side session data, rather than storing that information in the cookie itself (since otherwise someone could just edit the cookie anyway).

Comment: Thanks! Am I right in believing that securing the cookies to only send over SSL, with a session key will "lock" them anyway? The problem I can see by locking to IP is if on a laptop and taken from home to work etc...?

Comment: A cookie sent over SSL is encrypted along with the rest of the SSL session (so they can't be intercepted with firesheep et al), but I don't think HTTP makes any hard requirements about the cookie data being stored encrypted.  I believe the major browsers do use local encrypted cookie stores for SSL cookies, however.